SPO - Creating a Document Library template but retaining the content (Powershell)
Since MS took it upon themselves to remove the ability to create templates from the settings screen I have been looking for a way to create templates using PowerShell.  I am using the following to create a template, that works well but the bit I am missing is being able to capture the contents (which you used to be able to do in the old days).  Is this just not possible doing it through PowerShell or am I missing a trick.
$ListTemplate = Get-SPOSiteScriptFromList -ListUrl $ListURL  
$SiteScript = Add-SPOSiteScript -Title $TemplateName -Description $TemplateDescription -Content $ListTemplate   
Add-SPOListDesign -Title $TemplateName -Description $TemplateDescription -SiteScripts $SiteScript.Id -ListIcon Savings -ListColor Blue

Any help gratefully recevied.

As per my knowledge, it is not possible currently using these PowerShell commands.

The traditional method of saving a list or library as a template with content directly from the UI is no longer available in SharePoint Online.
What you could try as a very inconvenient workaround is copying the items and recreating them:
$items = Get-PnPListItem -List "YourList"
$items | Export-Csv -Path "listitems.csv" -NoTypeInformation
Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate -Path "template.xml"

$csv = Import-Csv -Path "listitems.csv"
foreach ($row in $csv) {
    Add-PnPListItem -List "YourList" -Values @{"Title"=$row.Title; "Column1"=$row.Column1; "Column2"=$row.Column2}
}


Thanks for the reply, yes it is a shame that MS keep removing/reducing functionality.  I've managed to use Flow to build a document library and populate it, bit of a faff but it works.
